# Problem with installing Ubuntu on Nexus7 in a VM

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I met a problem while installing Ubuntu on my Nexus7 in a Virtual Box VM. Although the tablet was unlocked and successfully loaded with fastboot method, installation stuck while erasing data. Why would it happen?

Comment: What on this earth are you saying? You tried installing ubuntu on nexus 7 using a Virtual Box VM.
I'd offer all my reputation as bounty to someone who can answer this question satisfactorily.

Comment: If you are running **Ubuntu** under Virtual Box, you may not be able to successfully 'write' to Nexus 7. You really need native control of the USB port. The installer would take some time to 'download' the images (from Internet) - but would then stall, just after (or before ?) it asks for your *sudo* password.  ***Please add more details to your question.***

Comment: Yes, i am running Ubuntu under Virtual Box and try to install Ubuntu on my nexus 7, everything is ok the  images of Ubuntu was downloaded also, the tablet also can be linked PC via fastboot method; but  when i run Ubuntu installer on PC, it doesn't work on the step of earsing data before write to nexus 7.

Comment: can you tell me what is the

Comment: can you tell me what does it mean about "native control of the USB port "?

Comment: it seems that the installer stopped on process of "erasing boot partition"

Comment: Did you check for **connectivity**, as suggested (below) by @mfisch?

Answer (score 4):

Try running fastboot devices from the command-line, if it doesn't show any devices, then it won't work.  I seriously doubt you can install it from a VM.  You could try using an Ubuntu live-cd on you system though.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to succesfully install Ubuntu to my Nexus7 using a VM of Ubuntu in Windows7.

I used the Nexus7 toolkit to ensure I had the correct drivers, I unlocked via windows and then installed via Ubuntu. I had no issues getting this setup and working using the ubuntu-nexus7-installer.